# Knockout : foreach, selectedvalue

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

```
{
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "selectedToppingId": "",
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
}
```

I would like to display radio buttons with the choice of topping.
The code could look like :

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: topping">
      <input type="radio" name="apps" data-bind="attr: { value: $data}, 
        checked: $parent.selectedTopping"/>
      <span data-bind="text: $data"/>
      <br/>
    </div>
```

How can I organize my viewModel to bind radioButtons and selectedTopping (selectedToppingId must take toppingId of the choice) ?

(Data = MyJSON)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is wrong with the snippet that you gave was the `<span data-bind="text: $data"/>`  it needs to be `<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>` for it to work with knockout.  I am not entirely clear on what your after but below is a working example of the what you provided.  there are a couple of ways that I think that you could go.  you can either map the incoming data yourself to your own client side view-model or you could use something like knockout.mapping to convert the incoming json data to knockout view-models.

```js
var data = {
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "selectedToppingId": "",
  "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
};

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.toppings = ko.observableArray(data.topping);
  self.selectedTopping = ko.observable("5007");

  return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: toppings">
  <input type="radio" name="apps" data-bind="attr: { value: $data.id}, 
        checked: $parent.selectedTopping" />
  <span data-bind="text: $data.type"></span>
  <br/>
</div>

<p>Selected Topping Id is
  <div data-bind="text: selectedTopping"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will display radio buttons based on the list, and save the selected ID back to your `selectedToppingId` variable:

```js
   var data =
{
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "selectedToppingId": "",
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
}

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.toppings = ko.observableArray(data.topping);
  self.selectedTopping = ko.observable("5007");

  self.selectedTopping.subscribe(function(newValue) {
 //Find selected item from parent array 
 var result = $.grep(data.topping, function(e){ return e.id == newValue; })[0];
 
 //Assign the ID back to our data
 selectedToppingId = result.id;
  });

  return self;
};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: toppings">
  <input type="radio" name="apps" data-bind="attr: {value: $data.id}, 
        checked: $parent.selectedTopping" />
  <span data-bind="text: $data.type"></span>
  <br/>
</div>

<p>Selected Id:
  <div data-bind="text: selectedTopping"></div>
</p>
```